# Python Celery Chain of Tasks on a Single Node

Tags: python, celery

I have two celery nodes on 2 machines (n1, n2) and my task enqueue is on another machine (main).
The main machine may not know the available node names.
My question is whether there is any guarantee that a chain of tasks will run on a single node.

```
res = chain(generate.s(filePath1, filePath2), mix.s(), sort.s())
```

the problem is that various tasks are using local data files that are node specific.
My guess is that chain is probably like chords which the doc explicitly says that there is no guarantee to run on a single node.
and if my guess about chain is right, then my next question is would the following be a good solution as an alternative to chains?

single task = guaranteed single node

```
@app.task
def my_chain_of_tasks():
    celery.current_app.send_task('mymodel.tasks.generate', args=[filePath1, filePath2]).get()
    celery.current_app.send_task('mymodel.tasks.mix').get()
    # do these 2 in parallel:
    res1 = celery.current_app.send_task('mymodel.tasks.sort')
    res2 = celery.current_app.send_task('mymodel.tasks.email_in_parallel')
    res1.get()
    return res2.get()
```

or is this still going to send the tasks to the message queue and cause the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a `.get()` on a task inside another task which is counter productive. Also there is no guarantee that all those tasks will be executed on a single node.

If You want a few tasks to be executed by particular node, you can queue them or route them accordingly.

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'mymodel.task.task1': {'queue': 'queue1'},
    'mymodel.task.task2': {'queue': 'queue2'}
}
```

Now you can start two workers to consume them

```
celery worker -A your_proj -Q queue1
celery worker -A your_proj -Q queue2
```

Now all `task1` will be executed by worker1 and `task2` by worker2.

Docs: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#manual-routing

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can I specify CELERY_ROUTES on the main machine? The main machine is not running celery. It's just enqueuing tasks in the message queue.

Comment: thats fine. you can specify routes in celery config file. when you run worker on a remote machine, it consumes only relevant tasks from broker

Comment: thanks. Let me figure out a setup to try it out; then I'll mark your answer.

Comment: The problem is that in your example, I need to have different tasks but my goal is to run the same task with different parameters on different queue. Any ideas?

Comment: then you can put a conditional check for parameters and route accordingly?

Comment: Right. I think this would get messy. I'll just run separate rabbitmq's on each target machine. The only problem with this is that the flower monitoring is not going to be centralized.

Comment: i am not sure if there is a way to route tasks based on params. you might get support for multiple brokers https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/111